# Failed to Autowire Configuration file with FeatureManager in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, autowired, togglz

I am trying to implement togglz with my spring boot application. Here my approach towards it is in two ways.
 Firstly below are the common files for my both usecase approaches.
ToggleController.java

```
package com.learn.poc.toggle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.togglz.core.manager.FeatureManager;

@Controller
public class ToggleController {
@Autowired
private FeatureManager manager;


@GetMapping("/testing")
@ResponseBody
String display() {

    if(manager.isActive(MyFeatures.FEATURE_ONE)){
        return "FeatureOne is active woking "+MyFeatures.FEATURE_ONE.isActive();
    }
    else {
        return "FeatureOne is Inactive redirected "+MyFeatures.FEATURE_ONE.isActive();
    }
  }
}
```

MyFeatures.java

```
package com.learn.poc.toggle;

import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.annotation.Label;
import org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext;

public enum MyFeatures implements Feature {

@Label("First Feature")
FEATURE_ONE,

@Label("Second Feature")
FEATURE_TWO;

public boolean isActive() {
    return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
}
}
```

Application.properties:(PS: I don't want to set anything directly in application properties like feature-enum etc...)

```
togglz.console.enabled=true
togglz.console.path=/togglz-console
server.servlet.context-path=/api
server.port=8080
togglz.console.use-management-port=false
#togglz.console.secured=false
#togglz.feature-enums=com.learn.poc.toggle.MyFeatures
```

Now for UseCase-1:
I am using configuration file implementing TogglzConfig.
MyTogglzConfiguration.java

```
package com.learn.poc.toggle;
import java.io.File;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.manager.TogglzConfig;
import org.togglz.core.repository.StateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.repository.file.FileBasedStateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.user.FeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.SimpleFeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider;

@Component
public class MyTogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {
public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
    return MyFeatures.class;
}
public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
    return new FileBasedStateRepository(new File("PATH\features.properties"));
}
@Override
public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    return new UserProvider() {
        @Override
        public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
            return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
        }
    };
}
}
```

So if i follow the above way its not getting autowired i.e not taking properties file from path and its not getting features anything at all.

UseCase-2: Insted i used spring ConfigFile and created bean for individual property as shown below.
configClass.java

```
package com.learn.poc.toggle;

import java.io.File;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.togglz.core.manager.EnumBasedFeatureProvider;
import org.togglz.core.repository.StateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.repository.file.FileBasedStateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider;
import org.togglz.core.user.FeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.SimpleFeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider;

@Configuration
public class configClass {

@Bean
public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
    return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(MyFeatures.class);
}
@Bean
public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
    System.out.println("in state");
    return new FileBasedStateRepository(new File("PATH\features.properties"));
}

@Bean
public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    System.out.println("in user provider");
    return new UserProvider() {
        @Override
        public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
            return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
        }
    };
}
}
```

If implement as above file its everything working fine. I don't know that first usecase is failing. Because its mentioned in the togglz documentation that if you mention configuration file as @Component it will automatically wired for spring boot.

ref: https://www.togglz.org/documentation/configuration.html

Its said that:

```
Togglz offers a special integration module for Spring. This module will automatically search for 
implementations of the TogglzConfig in Spring's ApplicationContext. Therefore you just have to 
declare your implementation as a class managed by Spring. If you are using the Spring annotation 
support you can just add a @Component annotation to your class:
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to implement TogglzConfig in your configuration class. The class below works for me in Spring boot app.

```
package com.cfa.restsolutions.menu.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.manager.EnumBasedFeatureProvider;
import org.togglz.core.manager.TogglzConfig;
import org.togglz.core.repository.StateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.JDBCStateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.spi.FeatureProvider;
import org.togglz.core.user.FeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.SimpleFeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class MyTogglzConfig implements TogglzConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
        return MyFeatures.class;
    }

    @Bean
    public FeatureProvider featureProvider() {
        return new EnumBasedFeatureProvider(MyFeatures.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
        return new JDBCStateRepository(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
        return new UserProvider() {
            @Override
            public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
                return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```